# Build an Eclipse workspace with TeamCity

Tags: eclipse, gcc, teamcity

I am in the process of converting our existing custom continuous build system to use TeamCity. This appears to work well for most of our build scenarios but one.

We have a hardware project that is set up to build using Eclipse configured with a specific set of tool chains. Developers run the IDE, and for lack of an Eclipse build runner, TeamCity builds the project from the commandline runner using python scripts.

The TeamCity build process is as follows:

- Delete the contents of the Eclipse workspace.
- import all the Eclipse projects into the workspace.
- build the workspace.

The problems with this approach are as follows:

- There is no build runner for Eclipse. The scripts work, but there is overhead in developing and maintaining the scripts. This is the very thing we are trying to get away from.
- There is no TeamCity parsing of the output (gcc and eclipse). I have to redirect the eclipse output to file, and when the Eclipse process finishes, parse the file for errors, warnings, progress status, etc., in order to inject the appropriate TeamCity service message to stdout. Again this kind of overhead is the very thing we are trying to get away from.

Given no Eclipse build runner just days away from release, is there a better mechanism for loading and building an Eclipse workspace with TeamCity?

Given the commandline runner script solution, is there a better machnism for capturing and displaying errors, warnings, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best approach for you at this particular time in your release cycle, given that you are so close to your release deadline, but I would use Maven for the build and use the M2E plugin to provide Maven integration inside of Eclipse.

While using Maven as a build tool is usually not overly complex, it is sometimes not trivial to convert an existing project to use it.

I would suggest that you start off your next release cycle by enabling Maven as your build tool - TeamCity fully supports the Maven build runner.

Comment: Gradle is also an option. May be less invasive for legacy project.